# Disable TTY reception using IOCTL

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, tty

I could not find an answer to the following question related to TTY port:

How can reception of data can be inhibited, while transmission is in progress?
I am expecting to have an IOCTL available for this but I could not find the answer in "man tty_ioctl" or elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate (don't know enough about TTYs to judge): [automatically changing RTS for RS-485 communication](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25250731/464709).

Comment: Thank you Frédéric, The problem is that my TTY is an FTDI connected trough USB (emulated TTY).  I found on https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt  some info about this. There is a section named 
2. HARDWARE-RELATED CONSIDERATIONS. They say something that HW shall support this. I must dig deeper in this direction. Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Rather than inhibit reception, which implies loss of data, you could use flow control (either HW or SW) to inhibit *transmission* by the other end.  Both ends of the serial link would have to be configured for flow control.