RS485 on Pocket Beagle
I am using pocket beagle with debian 10.3th vserion. I just want to know is there is any dtbo file there to start rs485 in pocket beagle?
Like; BBB have “BB-UART4-RS485-00A0.dtbo”, dtbo for pocket beagle is there or not.
Requirements: I don’t want to take care of enable pin in code. i want any driver/overlay take cares of Enable pin according to communication btw Master & slave.
Need to make changes in any dtbo?
is DTBO available?
have to take care code only?

Thank you and Welcome to Stack overflow. This question belongs to and hence should be migrated to Electrical Engineering SE (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Please post there for more and better chances to get replies.

"i want any driver/overlay take cares of Enable pin ..." - What you want is only possible if the Linux device driver has implemented that capability (otherwise you would have to add such a feature to the driver). Support for RS485 in the Linux kernel is essentially limited to U[S]ARTs that have explicit hardware support. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250731/automatically-changing-rts-for-rs-485-communication/25253003#25253003. Lucky for you, the TI SoC seems to have RS485 support in HW, and the OMAP serial driver supports that RS485 feature.

@sawdust I modified the "BB-UART4-RS485-00A0.dtbo" changed it to PB-UART-RS485-00A0.dtbo. but i am not getting dtbo working as expected.

' fr@1
P2_07_pinmux { status = "disabled"; };
P2_05_pinmux { status = "disabled"; };
P2_17_pinmux { status = "disabled"; };
fr@2
0x0844 0x26
0x0840 0x2E
0x087C 0x07
fr@3
status = "okay";
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&bb_uart4_rs485_pins>;
rs485-rts-delay = <0 0>;
rts-gpio = <&gpio2 1 1>;
rs485-rts-active-high;
linux,rs485-enabled-at-boot-time;
